# Struts2 jqGrid Refresh Button Text

Tags: jquery, struts2, jqgrid

I have a Struts2 jqGrid on a page. I have the nav bar with the standard refresh button in the default location. My users want the mouse-over text of the button to be "Refresh" instead of the default "Reload Grid". I haven't not been able to find an attribute to specify the text for that button. Below is my code:

```
    <s:url var="remoteurl" action="FraudAbuseJsonTableData"/>
    <sjg:grid
        altRows="false"
        id="gridtable"
        dataType="json"
        filter="true"
        filterOptions="{stringResult:true}"
        gridModel="gridModel"
        height="600"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        loadonce="true"
        navigator="true"
        navigatorAdd="true"
        navigatorAddOptions="{reloadAfterSubmit:true,addCaption:'Add Record'}"
        navigatorDelete="false"
        navigatorRefresh="true"
        navigatorSearch="true"
        onSelectRowTopics="rowselect"
        pager="true"
        pagerButtons="true"
        rowList="25,50,100"
        rowNum="25"
        rownumbers="true"
    >
        <sjg:gridColumn name="hostHomeCd" index="hostHomeCd" title="Host/Home" sortable="true"  width="100" sorttype="select" editable="true" />
        <sjg:gridColumn name="prvIdNbr" index="prvIdNbr" title="Prov Num" sortable="true" width="100" search="true" searchoptions="{sopt:['eq','ne']}" editable="true"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="fraudBegDt" index="fraudBegDt" title="Start Date" sortable="true" formatter="date" formatoptions="{newformat : 'm/d/Y', srcformat : 'Y-m-d H:i:s'}" editable="true"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="fraudEndDt" index="fraudEndDt" title="End Date" sortable="true" formatter="date" formatoptions="{newformat : 'm/d/Y', srcformat : 'Y-m-d H:i:s'}" editable="true"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="remainingDays" index="remainingDays" title="Days Remaining" sortable="true" width="75" editable="false"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="userIdNbr" index="userIdNbr" title="UserID" sortable="true"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="lastUpdtDt" index="lastUpdtDt" title="Update Date" sortable="true" formatter="date" formatoptions="{newformat : 'm/d/Y', srcformat : 'Y-m-d H:i:s'}" editable="true"/>
    </sjg:grid>
```

The above code works fine. At the bottom of my jsp I have the following:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#refresh_gridtable").text("Refresh"); // DOES NOT WORK!!!!!
    </script>
```

Using Firebug I found that the ID of the button is "refresh_gridTable" but running .text() on that ID does nothing. Any help with updating the Mouse-over text on the refresh button would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Provide your own localization file. As for changing it with js -> set title of that element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text of the tooltip come from `title` attribute of an element. So to change it dynamically you should use something like

```
$("#refresh_gridtable").attr("title", "Refresh");
```

It's important of case that you execute the code **after** the grid and the navigator bar is already created.

By the way there are exist `refreshtitle` option of `navGrid` which will be set typically in locale file. One can specify is as the parameter of `navGrid`. Alternatively one can set it as the property of `$.jgrid.nav`. Try to include the code

```
$.jgrid.nav = $.jgrid.nav || {};
$.jgrid.nav.refreshtitle = "Refresh";
```

**before** `navGrid` is created. You can use the code *instead of* setting `title` attribute by `$("#refresh_gridtable").attr("title", "Refresh")`.

Comment: Thank you Oleg. I added onCompleteTopics then subscribed the function with the first part. It works if I add the code at the end of the page, but not at the beginning (which for my needs is perfectly fine). 

`onCompleteTopics="loadComplete"

$.subscribe('loadComplete', function (event, data){
 $("#refresh_gridtable").attr("title", "Refresh");
});`